# Jquery .replace crashes browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

This line of code (I believe) looks for a substring starting with foo and ending with bar, that contains anything, including line breaks, and removes it from the string.

```
zip = string.replace(/foo(.|\s)*bar/, '');
```

For some reason, when I put a very large string through this, with a large portion NOT in between foo and bar it crashes Chrome. Chrome doesn't display any error messages, neither does the console, but the tab freezes, and refuses to do anything but close.

With relatively small contents outside, this doesn't crash, and with a large amount of content inside foo and bar, it doesn't crash. It isn't because the string is too large, JS has no limits on it's strings, and other .replace functions are working with the same size of string. Could it be a badly written regex or something?

Comment: Well, its syntax is a little weird... `(.|\s)*` is `(capture anything but a new line OR capture whitespace){as many times as needed}`, but JavaScript doesn't have a mode to have `.` match `new line` characters... Have you tried `/foo[\s\S]*bar/` instead?

Comment: It looks like that works -_- I thought my syntax was weird, but I wasn't sure how else to go about it.

Comment: A problem here is that the `.*` is *greedy*.  If you don't want "bar" to be among the stuff between "foo" and "bar", then you should use the non-greedy quantifier `*?` instead of `*`

Comment: @Pointy That makes sense, but then why did it work with a relatively small amount of string outside of the regex?

Comment: and why does @pete s answer fix it, because it's still greedy?

Comment: I just realized my comment did not capture anything... Does it crash if you add capturing? `/foo([\s\S]*)bar/`?

Comment: The browser crashes/freezes, most probably due to backtracking hell, since the `|` will cause branching and later backtracking, while a character class will not.

Comment: @pete, nope works either way. I'm combining answers now: `/foo[\s\S]*?bar/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser crashes with the regex `/foo(.|\s)*bar/`, while not for `/foo[\s\S]*bar/` as suggested by pete due to backtracking hell.

An (unoptimized) NFA regex engine will try the first branch, and it will backtrack to the 2nd branch if match fails. A better engine will can analyze the syntax, and combine the `.` and `\s` together into a character class so that it will not waste time backtracking.

Let us consider this input:

```
foo           notba     other
```

For the regex `/foo(.|\s)*bar/`, since a space (ASCII 32) can match both `.` and `\s`, after match fail for `.` branch, it will try for `\s` branch:

```
foo           notba     other
   ^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^
```

The number of space character is the number of levels of the binary tree explored by the regex engine. The time complexity increases exponentially by the number of whitespace characters, if the string contains `foo` but does not contain `bar`.

Consider pete's modification `/foo[\s\S]*bar/`, there is no branching, since everything has been checked by the character class, so when we backtrack on failure, we don't have any unexplored branch and will return failure quickly.

Comment: I'm choosing this answer for its full explanation of branching.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `(.|\s)*` is a little weird.

It's basically `(capture anything but a new line OR capture whitespace){as many times as needed}`, but then again JavaScript doesn't have a mode to have . match new line characters.

Try `/foo([\s\S]*)bar/` instead. The `[\s\S]` character class matches a character that is either a whitespace character (including line break characters), or a character that is not a whitespace character. Since all characters are either whitespace or non-whitespace, this character class matches any character. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

The reason for the crash is very likely "backtracking hell" as suggested by [nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh)